# Delannoy numbers in 3 dimensions

Tags: combinatorics

Is anyone aware of something analogous to Delannoy numbers in 3 dimensions? In addition to going left, right and diagonally in the plane, movement is possible to adjacent squares above (see the diagram).

[image: possible moves from a given square]

Comment: This 2011 paper by Caughman et al. counts the number of $d$-dimensional Delannoy paths:  https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81172932.pdf

Comment: Thanks. That answers my question.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, if $D(a,b,c)$ is the number of paths from $(0,0,0)$ to $(a,b,c)$, then

\begin{align}
D(a,b,c)
  &=[x^ay^bz^c]\frac1{1-x-y-z-xy-xz-yz-xyz}
\\&=[x^ay^bz^c]\frac1{2-(1+x)(1+y)(1+z)}
\\&=[x^ay^bz^c]\sum_{k=0}^\infty (\tfrac12)^{k+1}(1+x)^k(1+y)^k(1+z)^k
\\&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{-(k+1)}\binom{k}a\binom{k}b\binom{k}c.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

The paper sited by Jim Ferry provides a complete answer to my question. I just wanted to add a visual example for a 5×5×3 structure:

[image: Visual example for 5x5x3 structure]